# Spring: How to configure a Spring bean definition to return the same bean instance when passing the same arguments

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, prototype

Suppose, I have a `prototype` bean of type `A` and the class `A` is as simple as this:

```
public class A {

  private final int x;

  // Constructor, getter
}
```

And I would like to somehow configure Spring to return the same instance of `A` when I ask for a bean with the same parameter `x`.

If I do a bean definition like this

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public void getA(int x) {
  return new A(x);
}
```

... then any call to `context.getBean(A.class, x)` will return a new instance of `A` but I would like to get same instances when passing the same x values. Is there a way to build such a configuration without manually implementing a cache of constructed `A` instances?

Comment: prototype scope would always return different instances. That is how it works. Change it to singleton if the same instance is needed

Comment: The goal is to return different instances for different parameters and the same instances for the same parameters.